# Who were the other European astronomers who identified new stars around the time of Tycho Brahe?

Tags: astronomy, astronomers

Wikipedia notes:

> Early European astronomers such as Tycho Brahe identified new stars in the night sky (later termed novae), suggesting that the heavens were not immutable.

Who were the other European astronomers who identified new stars around the time of Tycho Brahe?

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, May 23). Star. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 18:38, June 3, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Star&oldid=898392700

Comment: SN 1572, SN 1604, code names with SN = super nova, for which Wikipedia gives names.

Comment: It's not hard to find lists of astronomers' dates of birth/research/death.  Maybe you could do a little reading and try to make this question more targeted?

Comment: The OP actually says "nova" not "supernova".  Presumably there were a lot more of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For novae there is a listing at [CBAT](http://www.cbat.eps.harvard.edu/nova_list.html).

Here are the first few listed.  The discoverer is in the last column.

```
DESIG.         DATE (UT)        R.A. (2000.0) Decl.         Mag. Range  REF.    DISCOVERER(S)  
04550 Leo N?? N1612 03 30       09 37.3     +15 15           4                  Scheiner                                            
CK    Vul N:  N1670 06 20       19 47.6     +27 19      1    2.6   20.7         Anthelm                                             
03846 Pup N?   1673 01 12       07 59.0     -43 49           3     20           Richer                                              
V529  Ori N?  N1678 03 28       05 58.4     +20 15           6     20.5         Hevelius                                            
WY    Sge N   N1783             19 32.7     +17 45      1    6     19.5         d'Agelet
```

Comment: On that site you linked to the supernova list includes the discoverers for the one Brahe noted in 1572: http://www.cbat.eps.harvard.edu/lists/Supernovae.html  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This sentence in Wikipedia does not say "around the time of Brahe". One early astronomer who identified a new star was Hipparchus. According to the information about him that reached us, this was the reason for him to make the first star catalog. In 1054 Chinese astronomers observed a supernova in Crab Nebula, whose remains can be seen now.

Astronomers who observed the  nova of 1604 were Kepler and Galileo (who lived approximately at the time of Brahe. There is no doubt that many other, less famous astronomers observed it as well. Brahe's nova was in 1572.

Comment: Who were the astronomers who reported these events or where can I find a list of them?